# python log stderr and stdout to a file

Tags: python, logging, stdout, stderr

Just wanted to pick your brains on this.  I have several subprocesses running and I wanted to print the stderr and stdout to a file.  I've done this so far:

```
def write_to_stderr_log(process):
    stderr= open("stderr.log", "w")
    proc_err = process.communicate()
    print >> stderr, proc_err
    stderr.close()

def write_to_stdout_log(process):
    stdout = open("stdout.log", "w")
    proc_out = process.communicate()
    print >> stdout, proc_out
    stdout.close()

def logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger('error_testing')
    hdlr = logging.FileHandler('error.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr)
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    logger.error('We have a problem')
    logger.debug('debugging')
    logger.info('some info')

logger()
proc = subprocess.Popen(['FastTree -nt test.fasta'], bufsize=512, stdin = None, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 

write_to_stderr_log(proc)
write_to_stdout_log(proc)
```

Is this the best way to do this.  If I have more than one process, I guess its going to re-write the log files, so that could be a problem.  Appreciate some advice here. Thanks

Comment: @nrpeterson this one is about redirecting the output of a child process

Comment: Ah, you have a point.  My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can provide your own `file` instances as keywords to `subprocess.Popen`.

```
>>> out = open('stdout.log', 'wb')
>>> err = open('stderr.log', 'wb')
>>> child = subprocess.Popen('FastTree -nt test.fasta', stdin=None, stdout=out,
                             stderr=err)
>>> rc = child.wait()
>>> out.close()
>>> err.close()
```

Here's the portion of the [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) documents that matters:

> *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are `PIPE`, `DEVNULL`, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing *file object*, and `None`. `PIPE` indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created. `DEVNULL` indicates that the special file `os.devnull` will be used. With the default settings of `None`, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent. Additionally, `stderr` can be `STDOUT`, which indicates that the `stderr` data from the applications should be captured into the same file handle as for `stdout`.

Comment: That hasnt worked.  If I introduce an error on the 'FastTree' subprocess, nothing is printed to the stderr.log file.

Comment: Try adding `shell=True` though I doubt that will have any effect.